# Intercepting the Move Item function between source and destination

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, outlook-2010

I've successfully captured the ItemMove function the way I need to (mostly) using the Redemption libraries.  My next task may be impossible, but I won't know unless I ask.

Part of what I'm writing involves moving messages from the Exchange inbox to a PST and potentially removing the attachment.  This is being done because our network thrashing is taking a big hit in regards to PST replication over DFSR (yes, I 'm aware of the PST/network issues and MS recommendations, but you go try explaining that to the users when you don't have money for training or new archiving software).  I'd like to be able to do the following via code:

1)  User selects message(s) and drags them to a PST folder
2)  Add-in intercepts this, copies the messages to a temporary PST on a local drive
3)  Attachments are processed in the local PST and saved to their appropriate network destination
4)  Messages are moved into the true destination PST on the network.

This multi-step process is necessary as we have quotas on both drive space as well as maximum PST file size.  Since PST compression doesn't happen automatically and we can't programmatically force it, I've come up with this idea for a workaround.

Ideas and inspiration are welcome as usual.

-Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot intercept any drag/drop events in Outlook, at least not using any of the officieally supported APIs.
You will get ItemAdd event on the target folder, but it will only fire after the item was created and saved.

Comment: That's what I figured, Dmitry.  Am I stuck between a Redemption Rock and a Microsoft Hard Place on this one?

Comment: Pretty much... Just the way MAPI works - all notifications are asynchronous.